# Routing gateway through gateway

Tags: routing

I don't know how to give this a better title but my planned route is:

Host -> 192.168.1.254 -> 192.168.3.254 -> 192.168.3.0/24

I planned to do this by giving the routes

192.168.3.254 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.254

192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.254

but I ran into the trouble that it isn't working.

Can someone point out the flaw in my logic?

Answer (score 0):

IP packets do not have their full path encoded into them. All they carry is the final destination IP address, and each hop makes its own decision about where to send them.¹ Your host *itself* can choose to send the packet to router A, but it cannot force *another device* (router A) to send it next to router B.

The 'gateway' field in routes is often called the 'nexthop' field because the only thing it can describe is the immediate next device to send the packet to.² The address in the 'gateway' field it is translated to a MAC address, so it must be reachable directly on the same ethernet.

(This usually means that routes like "192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.3.254" are a contradiction in terms... Routers have multiple IP addresses – one on each side – so the 'gateway' field generally must be the address that's facing the sender, not the one facing the destination.)

If your host is 192.168.1.x, it should have this route:

```
192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.1.254
```

The router 192.168.1.254 should have its own route for 192.168.3.0/24 via router B.

---

*(¹ There are exceptions in large ISP networks, e.g. MPLS or Segment Routing, but that is not something you'll find in a home LAN.)*

*(² "Recursive" routes (like what you were trying) do exist in various systems, but they still do not actually specify the whole path – they're just an indirect way of writing the same "192.168.3.0/24 via 192.168.1.254".)*